# How can i set fee permanently via paytxfee command

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I have set default `paytxfee` of 0.001 in `bitcoin.conf` file. I have updated `paytxfee` value via `bitcoin-cli paytxfee 0.1` when I restarted bitcoin core value reset back to 0.001. is there is anyway i can set fee permanently.

Comment: set the fee while sending.

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing when running `bitcoin-cli paytxfee 0.1` command, you can run command to update value of `paytxfee` inside `bitcoind.conf` file.

like this:

```
bitcoin-cli paytxfee NEW_AMOUNT && sed -i 's/paytxfee=OLD_AMOUNT/paytxfee=NEW_AMOUNT/g' ~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

This will set fee for current session also when you restart bitcoin core price will not alter.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it persistent by adding a line `paytxfee=0.1` to your `bitcoin.conf` file.

You cannot make `bitcoind` persist the result of the `paytxfee` RPC.